# I would like to post my blender when I have issue, what are people using to post?

Tags: discussion

I have been a bit of nightmare with doing normal bakes recently, and it's time that i start posting my blend. Currently each time i try to bake, only the head of my female shows up baked in the normal map, the rest of the file is filled with various colors that do not conform to the uvmap I unwrapped. Since I'm at work, i won't be able to post until later, but people use google drive, dropbox, etc or what else?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/